# ASP.NET VB Code Behind - Error The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtpclient

I have some ASP.NET code that I need to send an email this is the procedure I have cribbed on how to do that and it tries to send the email but after a fairly long pause comes up with this full error message:

"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated."

I have poured over a lot of similar errors on this site and applied some of the fixes that should allow my code to send email and none work.

My ASP.NET code is running on a 2012 r2 Server that is on the same internal network as the mail server which is running Server 2008 r2 and Exchange Server 2013.

The ASP.NET server can be accessed via "remote.domainname.co.uk" and the Mail Server can be accessed via "mail.dommainname.co.uk" where domainname is a placeholder for the actual domain name.

This is the code that I am using:

```
    Dim mailto As New MailAddress("toaddress@mydomain.com") 'My developer email add for testing.
    Dim mailfrom As New MailAddress("fromaddress@domainname.co.uk")
    Dim message As New MailMessage(mailfrom, mailto), Msg As String = ""
    Dim mailClient As New SmtpClient()
    Dim UserAndPass As New NetworkCredential()
    Dim Script = ""
    Dim n As Integer = 0
    Dim BodyText As String = ""

    Try

        message.Subject = "Issue relating to " & p.IssueDescription & "."

        'Create the body text:
        BodyText = "This email is to bring to your attention the following issue:" & NNL
        BodyText += "Building: " & p.Building & NL
        BodyText += "Location: " & p.Location & NL
        BodyText += "Issue:" & p.IssueDescription & NL
        BodyText += "Additional Information:" & NNL
        BodyText += p.AdditionalInfo & NNL
        BodyText += "Sent from the XYZ Logging System." & NL
        BodyText += "Date: " & Now.ToShortDateString & NL
        BodyText += "Time: " & Now.ToShortTimeString

        message.Body = BodyText

        'send the message
        mailClient = New SmtpClient("mail.domainname.co.uk", 25) 
        mailClient.EnableSsl = True
        mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        mailClient.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("fromaddress@domainname.co.uk", "passwordtext")
        mailClient.Send(message)

        Script = "alert('"
        Script += "The Patrols Issue Email has been successfully sent!"
        Script += "')};"
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "alert", Script, True)

    Catch ex As Exception
        PEH("SendEmail", "frmName", ex.Message) 'My error handler


    Finally

        'f.Dispose()
        mailClient.Dispose()
        message.Dispose()


    End Try
```

On the Exchange server I have the standard set of receive connectors and I have checked that they are all configured as per the standard install and they are.  I did try creating my own receive connector but this caused problems with emails being sent from remote senders getting bounced with the same "Client was not authenticated" error so I removed it again.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Graham Sivill.

Comment: Ensure that the SMTP credentials are correct. If you are confident the credentials are correct, contact the administrator of the email server for further assistance?

Comment: further inspection and a bit of WireShark action, to check if the code is sending an Auth command to the server before starting a message, which could be the cause why it returns the Client not Authenticated error?

Comment: With deprecated versions of Windows Server, you might run into mismatches of SSL or TLS versions and what is actually available on the server. E.g. [Support for TLS System Default Versions included in the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows Server 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3154519/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-net-framework) - you can search for the exact OS versions. **Oh** and perhaps more usefully, [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, @Leskek P I am the admin on the Exchange Server and I know the credentials are correct in terms of user and pass, however I am not clear whether I should use user@domainnname.co.uk or domainname\user as I have not found a definitive definition of which form should be used?

Comment: @Andrew Morton - Thanks for the links I will have a look!

Comment: @Andrew Morton - I tried the links and tried changing my Dot Net version to 4.7.2 but it made no difference so I am still stumped.  I can only think it's an issue with the Exchange Server or something?

Comment: @Siv It looks like you're going to have to use [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) as [Leszek P suggested earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64012758/asp-net-vb-code-behind-error-the-server-response-was-5-7-1-client-was-not-aut#comment113195606_64012758). I assume you're aware that Server 2008 R2 was EOLed on January 14, 2020.

Comment: Yes fully aware of the EOL. No option to change it I am afraid at the moment.